# Haproxy stats for multiple fronends

Tags: haproxy

I have haproxy configured with three frontends: http7001, http7002, and http7003 using the same backend
in config the stats is enabled as:

```
listen stats *:9001
mode http
stats enable
stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
stats uri /haproxy_stats
stats auth admin:admin
```

every time I hit haproxy_stats page either via browser (for regular html) or curl (for csv), I'm getting frontend stats only for one of configured frontends (randomly http7001 or http7002 or http7003)
For example:

Respose#1

http7001,FRONTEND,,,0,18,2000,162045,858272517,3395311531,0,0,307,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,1,0,101,,,,0,150399,5097,990,5742,18,,1,101,162246,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,
,,

Response#2

http7003,FRONTEND,,,0,38,2000,213336,1306426186,3217983292,0,0,315,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,3,3,0,,,,0,0,0,103,,,,0,200323,6419,863,5839,48,,0,103,213492,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,

Tried to search on internet how to get the stats either for all configured frontends at once or to specify what frontend to get the stats for in the request being sent but didn't find literally anything which could be an indicator that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong... though three frontends pointed to the same backend configuration doesn't look too exotic to me and it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Found on [Combine HAProxy stats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394592/combine-haproxy-stats?rq=1)
that "Haproxy keeps stats separated in each process. It has no capabilities to combine stats of multiple processes"
And it was exactly my case. Each frontend has its own process configured

```
frontend http7001
bind-process 1

frontend http7002
bind-process 2

frontend http7003
bind-process 3
```

So as solution I have configured three endpoints to access a corresponding frontend stats

```
listen stats1 *:9001
mode http
bind-process 1
stats enable
... 

listen stats2 *:9002
mode http
bind-process 2
stats enable
...

listen stats3 *:9003
mode http
bind-process 3
stats enable
...
```

Now I can access each frontend stats separately